# Do i need to dispose and unsubscribe from events for my BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, wpf, events, backgroundworker, dispose

I am creating short lived `BackgroundWorker`s and don't keep reference of them anywhere, do i need to clean up once they reach `RunWorkerCompleted` or will it be done automatically ?

Edit for code:

```
public void ScanForProcess(IntPtr selectedHandle)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += ScannerDoWork;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += OnScanCompleted;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync(selectedHandle);
}
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Better don't use a BackgroundWorker at all. Use [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) instead.

Comment: Provide your code, it will help us give you a more accurate, complete answer. Also, when you say unsubscribe events, can you clarify what you are referring to as events? Are you speaking of C# events declared with the keyword, or are these some kind of custom messaging classes such as integration events?

Comment: The code is pretty basic, i just subscribe to the `DoWork` and `RunWorkerCompleted` and that is it, edited my OP with it.

Comment: Use [TAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap) instead of legacy `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: Voting to **re-open** as OP appears to have provided code now

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if something implements `IDisposable` you should always invoke `Dispose()` during normal operation.  The issue is less about what happens today, and more about what might happen in the future - failing to dispose isn't contractually guaranteed to *not* leak something, basically.

`BackgroundWorker` extends `Component`, and `Component` does not trivial work in it's [`Dispose(bool)` method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/compmod/system/componentmodel/Component.cs,180), so you do risk leaking resources if your `BackgroundWorker` isn't disposed properly even today.

Comment: So in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler i add a `(sender as BackgroundWorker)?.Dispose();` at the end and i am fine ?